# Add Office 365 ProPlus license to Office Home & Business

Tags: microsoft-office, license

I have a Windows 10 computer with MS Office Home & Business installed. It is activated with a volume license.

I need MS Publisher, which is included in the Office 365 ProPlus bundle. I have more activations available on my 365 ProPlus license.

What happens if I enter my 365 ProPlus license into the existing Home & Business installation? Will I get Publisher, or will I get a mess?

Comment: "Will I get Publisher" - No;  You would need to change the product key for the Office installation and then install Publisher by using the Office configuration tool.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. So I don't need to uninstall Home & Business? Please explain where I would find the Office configuration tool.

Comment: [Office Configuration Web Tool](https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings).  You might be able to get away by just installing Publisher but you would still need to change the product key if you did that.